# Map to custom column names with ServiceStack OrmLite (Without Attributes)

Tags: servicestack, dapper, ormlite-servicestack

Per title - Is it possible to map

```
class Test {
   String SomeName {get; set;}
}
```

to SQL Table

```
tbl_test (name)
```

I am not interested to use attributes as I don't want to fill my POCOs with garbage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all ServiceStack libraries use the metadata API's in ServiceStack.Text, all attributes can also be added decoupled from the model itself using the fluent API below:

```
typeof(Test)
    .AddAttributes(new AliasAttribute("tbl_test"));
```

To add attributes on a property you can use the `GetProperty()` extension method, e.g:

```
typeof(Test)
    .GetProperty("SomeName")
    .AddAttributes(new AliasAttribute("p_some_name"));
```

These attributes need to be run once on Startup before they're accessed by any ServiceStack library.